# Is it possible to run a Deployed static site as localhost

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, webserver

I created a static site for my **IOT Devices** that are connected on my home WiFi and I can control them via **localhosted** website.

But it hasn't been running since I deployed the site to a **[Live Server](https://iotcarcontroller.netlify.app/)**.

So, is there any way to send commands to my home WiFi through a **deployed site**?

```js
 //passing commands through link

function lightOn(){
 location.href = "http://192.168.0.104/on";
}

function lightOff(){
 location.href = "http://192.168.0.104/off";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="lightOn()">Light On</button>
<button onclick="lightOff()">Light Off</button>
```

Comment: I used public IP in my router so that I can send commands to my Arduino at home

Comment: @Masood mine is also a Arduino-NodeMCU project. How to get public IP of it? any tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing you IoT device over the internet you will need:

1. A static public IP (Your ISP can provide)
2. A router with Port forwarding capability
3. An ethernet or Wifi module for your IoT device (Arduino)

For a complete tutorial follow this link:
https://www.instructables.com/Accessing-Arduino-over-internet/